# Get the root document object outside page.evaluate in Puppeteer.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer.js to crawl some pages. Currently, I'm using [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to perform a lot of queries on the DOM. Today it's impossible, as you can see in the following code, and explained in the comment:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // Instructs the blank page to navigate a URL
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Here I have the 'document' object available here. I want to evaluate it outside of this scope,
since I have here a lot of investigation of the DOM and I don't want to mess the puppeteer code here.
I can't call any outer function here.

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {});
```

Today, Instead of this, I need to export all the HTML page,
and send it to external package like jsdom in other file:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const pageContent = await page.content();
const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(pageContent);
const divs = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('div');
// Rest of the long investigation here.
```

What I need?

```
const dom = await page.contentDOM();
const divs = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('div');
    // Rest of the long investigation here.
```

So basically, my question is, there is some function built-in in Puppeeter.js that expose the document root object outside the `page.evaluate`, that will allow me to move the document to other function to investigate the DOM there, or I still need at this point to use external packages like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)?

Tried to look for answers here:
[Getting DOM node text with Puppeteer and headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202985/getting-dom-node-text-with-puppeteer-and-headless-chrome)
[Using puppeteer how do you get all child nodes of a node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700494/using-puppeteer-how-do-you-get-all-child-nodes-of-a-node)
[Getting all styles with devtool-protocol in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874888/getting-all-styles-with-devtool-protocol-in-puppeteer)
[Get DocType of an HTML as string with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript/27838954#27838954)
[Handling events from puppeteer's page context outside evaluate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180994/handling-events-from-puppeteers-page-context-outside-evaluate-method)
[Headless Chrome ( Puppeteer ) - how to get access to document node element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254398/headless-chrome-puppeteer-how-to-get-access-to-document-node-element)

I recently opened issue on Puppeeter.js GitHub page but with no answer:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6667

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert at scraping or anything like so I could be wrong, but I think puppeteer can do anything that jsdom can do, plus execute javascript. I have found these four functions really helpful

[page.$$](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageselector-1): gets elements using querySelectorAll and returns an array of [ElementHandle](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-class-elementhandle) to make usable in Node

[page.$](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageselector): gets element using querySelector and returns an ElementHandle to make usable in Node

[page.$$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args): executes callback on querySelectorAll and returns the callback result

[page.$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1): executes callback on querySelector and returns the callback result

If you want the html from the page I found this [answer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/406) :

```js
const renderedContent = await page.evaluate(() => new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document));
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not I'm looking for. I want to get the `document` with all the functions of 'getElementById` and `querySelectorAll`. This only gives me the string HTML. You can get it by the way, by `await page.content()`, it will be the same.

Comment: Have you considered using page.exposeFunction to load your functions into the page so that when you call page.evaluate it would be easier to read? Here's the doc for page.exposeFunction https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction

Comment: Even if this works, how does it answer my needs? I need an object like I get from jsDOM package - a root document with all the 'querySelectAll' and 'getElemenetById' kind of functions, outside the `page.evaluate` function.

Comment: I thought the reason you were using jsdom was because you had a lot of dom queries that you did not want to nest in the `page.evaluate`. Have you considered just forgetting puppeteer and using `JSDOM.fromURL`

Comment: I wish to combine all in one package. I need to perform crawling in specific parts, and perform a long DOM investigation in the other parts, but in the same URL.